# fan stopped working after using i8kutils on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, dell, fan

I had a really hard time with loud fan noise in Ubuntu 14.04. I came across an article with a solution using i8kutils package and it seemed to work fine. But now the fan has stopped working altogether. Any solutions?

Comment: Do you have the latest BIOS for your model of laptop installed?